# Windows shows more then 4 primary partition which are in fact Logical in ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ubuntu-12.04, logical-drive

I have installed Ubuntu 32-bit on Windows 32-bit.

Windows shows more then 4 primary partition which are in fact Logical in ubuntu. Help me Fix this without re-installing any OS.

Windows 7 disk management shows the following strange configuration and does not recognize all drives. Why is there more than 4 primary partitions? They are visible in Ubuntu but windows cant recognize it.
How can I tell windows that those partition are Logical and sda3 is the container for that.
If i will delete any partition from windows it will forbid me from creating another. So in most simplest that green square should start right after C drive and should extend up to HP Recovery partition. (I partitioned this hdd with ubuntu during installation)

[image: edisc managment]

Help me making all drives visible in Windows. 
Bellow is Screen shot taken from ubuntu for the same system.
[image: Ubuntu Disk managment]

Same using Gparted.
[image: Gparted screen shot]

Comment: Hello Samir, I insert your image and made it a little bit better to read. But your question title confuses me. It states the opposite to what you said in the question itself. Can you correct the title or correct the question or enlighten me what you mean? :)

Comment: related/dupe [Windows 8 Machines Only Have Primary Partitions?](http://superuser.com/q/523718)

Comment: I am sorry @Sathya , its not related, I have bios configuration with MBR based hdd, So it should have at most 4 Primary partition. Question you are taking about is system based on efi and GPT os can have any no of primary partition.

Comment: @SamirChauhan Are you sure?  I see a 100MB SYSTEM partition that is tipical of UEFI systems.

Comment: What test Can i perform to be certain for that? I have efi type booting perhaps but my windows is 32 bit, ubuntu live cd does not give option to boot in efi mode, and i tried creating more then four partition in windows but it denied, also 100 MB system partition is quite common with windows installation since long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution. its still not perfect. I have deleted sda7 and sda8 (10 gb and 90 gb) drives from windows, and it went to free space in logical drive container, the i created partitions in windows and its done in both, i am not concerned about sda5 and sda6 because it has / (Linux) and swap respectively and I dont want windows to recognize it.

bellow is screen shot of disk from windows and ubuntu.
[image: Windows scree shot]

And this is taken from ubuntu
[image: Ubuntu screen shot]

It is still not perfect in the sense Windows and ubuntu is showing it differently.
Windows has 4 primary partition and 3 logical as shown bye red line and dot in picture, which is unusual and yes ubuntu has almost same as i already had, except names changed.